# Undefined reference to boost using C++11

Tags: c++, boost, undefined-reference

I've tried with the solutions proposed in other topics but they didn't work for me. I'm compiling a program and after the configure script( in which all the links to the requested libraries are succesfully checked and verified), I get problems with the ''make all'' command, receiving output as the one below. Boost_1.64.0  has been compiled with the commands

```
./bootstrap.sh

./b2 toolset=gcc cxxflags=-std=c++11
```

and the same compiler(gcc/g++-4.8) I'm using for installing this program. All the links to the shared library files.so
(boost_filesystem,boost_programoptions,etc..) work without errors because I run the boost tutorial without problems.

```
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.9.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"OpenFoam\ Suite\ 0.9.0\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"suite\" -DVERSION=\"0.9.0\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DPACKAGE=\"suite\" -DVERSION=\"0.9.0\" -I.  -I/home/giuseppe/OpenFOAM/OpenSMOKEppSolvers/OpenSMOKEpp-master/source -I../../src -I/home/giuseppe/OpenFOAM/lib_flameletSMOKE/eigen-eigen-67e894c6cd8f -I/home/giuseppe/OpenFOAM/lib_flameletSMOKE/rapidxml-1.13 -I/home/giuseppe/OpenFOAM/lib_flameletSMOKE/boost_1_64_0/   -O3 -m64 -fPIC -std=c++11  -fopenmp   -MT ../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o -MD -MP -MF ../../src/licensegenerator/.deps/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.Tpo -c -o ../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o `test -f '../../src/licensegenerator/LicenseGenerator.cpp' || echo './'`../../src/licensegenerator/LicenseGenerator.cpp
mv -f ../../src/licensegenerator/.deps/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.Tpo ../../src/licensegenerator/.deps/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.Po
g++ -O3 -m64 -fPIC -std=c++11  -fopenmp   -L/home/giuseppe/OpenFOAM/lib_flameletSMOKE/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib -lboost_regex -lboost_timer -lboost_chrono -lboost_date_time -lboost_program_options -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system  -lgfortran  -o OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator.sh ../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o  
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `OpenSMOKE::CreateDirectory(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x99b): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directories(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x9a8): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `OpenSMOKE::OpenSMOKE_DictionaryGrammar::ErrorMessage(std::string) const':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x2530): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::filename() const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `OpenSMOKE::CheckKineticsFolder(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x327d): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x3331): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x33eb): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x342f): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x34ff): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x3539): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `OpenSMOKE::OpenInputFileASCII(std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, boost::filesystem::path)':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x4a9d): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `OpenSMOKE::InputFileDictionary::Status(std::ostream&) const':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x58cc): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::filename() const'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x5918): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::parent_path() const'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x5a07): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::file_size(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `OpenSMOKE::OpenSMOKE_DictionaryGrammar::ShortSummary(std::ostream&) const':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x5b5b): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::filename() const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `OpenSMOKE::OpenInputFileXML(rapidxml::xml_document<char>&, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::filesystem::path const&)':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x11b9e): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `OpenSMOKE::ImportReactionNames(boost::filesystem::path, unsigned int, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&)':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x12380): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `OpenSMOKE::OpenSMOKE_CheckLicense(boost::filesystem::path, std::string, unsigned int&)':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x17ae8): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text+0x17b55): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::string, char>::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&) const':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEE[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEE]+0x19): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, std::string*, int)'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC2ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i[_ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC5ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i]+0x26): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC2ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i[_ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC5ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i]+0x3c): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::string, char>::name() const':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE4nameEv]+0x25): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<unsigned int, char>::name() const':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcE4nameEv]+0x25): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::~error_with_option_name()':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options22error_with_option_nameD2Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options22error_with_option_nameD5Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::error_with_option_name'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::validation_error::~validation_error()':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorD2Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorD5Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::error_with_option_name'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::~invalid_option_value()':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueD2Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueD5Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::error_with_option_name'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::~error_with_option_name()':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options22error_with_option_nameD0Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options22error_with_option_nameD0Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::error_with_option_name'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::validation_error::~validation_error()':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorD0Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorD0Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::error_with_option_name'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueD0Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueD0Ev]+0xc): more undefined references to `vtable for boost::program_options::error_with_option_name' follow
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::date_time::ymd_formatter<boost::date_time::year_month_day_base<boost::gregorian::greg_year, boost::gregorian::greg_month, boost::gregorian::greg_day>, boost::date_time::simple_format<char>, char>::ymd_to_string(boost::date_time::year_month_day_base<boost::gregorian::greg_year, boost::gregorian::greg_month, boost::gregorian::greg_day>)':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9date_time13ymd_formatterINS0_19year_month_day_baseINS_9gregorian9greg_yearENS3_10greg_monthENS3_8greg_dayEEENS0_13simple_formatIcEEcE13ymd_to_stringES7_[_ZN5boost9date_time13ymd_formatterINS0_19year_month_day_baseINS_9gregorian9greg_yearENS3_10greg_monthENS3_8greg_dayEEENS0_13simple_formatIcEEcE13ymd_to_stringES7_]+0x1d5): undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string() const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::run()':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE3runEv[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE3runEv]+0x1b): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::get_canonical_option_prefix()'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE3runEv[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE3runEv]+0x50): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::run()'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_parsed_options<char> boost::program_options::parse_command_line<char>(int, char const* const*, boost::program_options::options_description const&, int, boost::function1<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string const&>)':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE[_ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE]+0x1ea): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::to_internal(std::string const&)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE[_ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE]+0x247): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE[_ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE]+0x270): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::set_options_description(boost::program_options::options_description const&)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE[_ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE]+0x289): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::style(int)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE[_ZN5boost15program_options18parse_command_lineIcEENS0_20basic_parsed_optionsIT_EEiPKPKS3_RKNS0_19options_descriptionEiNS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE]+0x2f5): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::set_additional_parser(boost::function1<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string const&>)'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `unsigned short boost::date_time::month_str_to_ushort<boost::gregorian::greg_month>(std::string const&)':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9date_time19month_str_to_ushortINS_9gregorian10greg_monthEEEtRKSs[_ZN5boost9date_time19month_str_to_ushortINS_9gregorian10greg_monthEEEtRKSs]+0x11a): undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::get_month_map_ptr()'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::variables_map::~variables_map()':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options13variables_mapD2Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options13variables_mapD5Ev]+0x3): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::variables_map'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `main':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x67): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::system_complete(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x8b): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::parent_path() const'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x142): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x17a): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x222): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::add_options()'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x240): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, char const*)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x259): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x272): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x28d): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x295): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::variables_map::variables_map()'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2d0): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::basic_parsed_options<char> const&, boost::program_options::variables_map&, bool)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x352): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::operator<<(std::ostream&, boost::program_options::options_description const&)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x464): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4f9): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x528): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::notify(boost::program_options::variables_map&)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x145c): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::operator<<(std::ostream&, boost::program_options::options_description const&)'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_LicenseGenerator.cpp':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x15bb): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x15c7): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text.startup+0x15d3): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::variables_map::~variables_map()':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options13variables_mapD0Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options13variables_mapD0Ev]+0x3): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::variables_map'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(boost::program_options::error_with_option_name const&)':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options22error_with_option_nameC2ERKS1_[_ZN5boost15program_options22error_with_option_nameC5ERKS1_]+0x2f): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::error_with_option_name'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o: In function `void boost::program_options::validate<unsigned int, char>(boost::any&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, unsigned int*, long)':
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options8validateIjcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISbIT0_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EESaIS9_EEPT_l[_ZN5boost15program_options8validateIjcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISbIT0_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EESaIS9_EEPT_l]+0x12): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validators::check_first_occurrence(boost::any const&)'
LicenseGenerator.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options8validateIjcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISbIT0_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EESaIS9_EEPT_l[_ZN5boost15program_options8validateIjcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISbIT0_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EESaIS9_EEPT_l]+0x146): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::invalid_option_value(std::string const&)'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE[_ZTIN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::program_options::error_with_option_name'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcEE[_ZTIN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcEE]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE[_ZTIN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE]+0x20): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE]+0x20): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcEE]+0x40): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool) const'
../../src/licensegenerator/OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE]+0x40): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator.sh] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is possibly caused by the incorrect order of parameters in the linker command line. All libraries that `OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o` depends on have to be specified after this object file in the command line. The linker loads the object files and libraries in the order they are specified in the command line, so every unresolved symbol reference from `OpenSMOKEpp_LicenseGenerator_sh-LicenseGenerator.o` needs to be satisfied by a later library. The same applies to all other libraries and/or object files in your linker command line.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this valuable experience!